# Metricbeat-Kafka-Logstash Configuration

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, elastic-stack, metricbeat

I want to send Metribeat data to Kafka. And from kafka to Logstash.

Here is my `metricbeat.yml`.

```
metricbeat.config.modules:
  # Glob pattern for configuration loading
  path: ${path.config}/modules.d/*.yml

  # Set to true to enable config reloading
  reload.enabled: false

setup.template.settings:
  index.number_of_shards: 1
  index.codec: best_compression

setup.dashboards.enabled: false

output.kafka:

    hosts: ["kafka:9092"]   // I only have one host. 
    topic: "%{[fields.log_topic]}"   
    compression: gzip

processors:
  - add_host_metadata: ~
  - add_cloud_metadata: ~
```

And from Kakfa to Logstash, this is the configuration file.

```
input {
    kafka {
            bootstrap_servers => "localhost:9092"
            topics => ["test"]
    }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]
    manage_template => false
    index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{[@metadata][version]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
```

From Logstash, I want to send data to Elasticsearch to be visualized by Kibana.

However,  I see no index in Elasticsearch.

I am doing `.\metricbeat.exe setup -e` (Windows) before running `.\start-service metricbeat`.

Elasticsearch server, Kibana server, Zookeeper server, Kafka server are running fine.

My logstash is looking okay. Below is what I see from my cmd.

> [2019-05-23T17:26:51,668][INFO ][org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser] Kafka version : 2.1.0
>   [2019-05-23T17:26:51,738][INFO ][org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser] Kafka commitId : eec43959745f444f
>   [2019-05-23T17:26:52,208][INFO ][org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata] Cluster ID: eJYo7GgaTZitGoeiROlk2w
>   [2019-05-23T17:26:52,211][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
>   [2019-05-23T17:26:52,222][INFO ][org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator] [Consumer clientId=logstash-0, groupId=logstash] Discovered group coordinator DESKTOP-MOVCIN1:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null)
>   [2019-05-23T17:26:52,229][INFO ][org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator] [Consumer clientId=logstash-0, groupId=logstash] Revoking previously assigned partitions []
>   [2019-05-23T17:26:52,231][INFO ][org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator] [Consumer clientId=logstash-0, groupId=logstash] (Re-)joining group
>   [2019-05-23T17:26:52,274][INFO ][org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator] [Consumer clientId=logstash-0, groupId=logstash] Successfully joined group with generation 23
>   [2019-05-23T17:26:52,281][INFO ][org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator] [Consumer clientId=logstash-0, groupId=logstash] Setting newly assigned partitions [test-0]

Can anyone give me some guidance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to collect system data with **Metricbeat**, send them to **Logstash** via **Kafka** and store them in **Elasticsearch** and see them in **Kibana**.

It isn't an ideal answer yet. I'll update it as I understand better in the future.

For `metricbeat.yml` configuration,

```
output.kafka:
    hosts: ["localhost:9092"] 
    topic: "testkafka"    // I created this topic in Kafka earlier.
```

For **Logstash** configuration,

```
input { 
    kafka { 
              bootstrap_servers => "localhost:9092"
              topics => ["testkafka"]
    }
}

output {
   elasticsearch { 
       hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
       index => "testkafka" 
   }
}
```

At least, with these configurations, I was able to integrate ELK with K(Kafka).